# Mootools - fadein div on hover class1 , stay visible and replace on hover class2

Tags: replace, mootools, fadein

I have a series of div's which are hidden on pageload

```
<div class="contact1"> Content here </div>
<div class="contact2"> Content here </div>
<div class="contact3"> Content here </div>
<div class="contact4"> Content here </div>
```

With this comes a series of hyperlinks with classes

```
<a href="link-to-item-1" class"contact1">
<a href="link-to-item-1" class"contact1">
<a href="link-to-item-1" class"contact1">
<a href="link-to-item-1" class"contact1">
```

On mouseover, I want the corresponding div to fadein or be set visible, and on mouseleave it should stay visble. Whenover you hover one of the other class, this should be replaced with the corresponding div.

I experimented some with jQuery, and I'm sure I can make a fadein / out in mootools as well, but with this replacement I'm lost. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: You have to bring us some code so we can help you, we can't do the work for you :)

Comment: I can understand that, I just never have been into Mootols alot, did some stuff with JQuery, I will try and design an example today ;)

Problem is the site I use already has mootools as library, so it makes no sense to just get JQuery as well, for just 1 simple script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.fade()` Mootools method and `Fx.Tween.chain()` to chain multiple animations.

See **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/gKkQq/1/)** for result and commented code.
I assumed you want to hide all divs at beginning (I did it using normal CSS).
And don't forget to have a look at Mootools official documentation about the methods I used :)